# How to Move up and down in ASP.NET Gridview Using Arrow Keys

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I Have A Grid view control in that grid view controls ItemTemplate i have taken textboxes now i want to do is that on pressing down arrow key the cursor which is in first textbox of first row will go to the first textbox of second row

This is the Grid view which i want to do the up down

Comment: Use this URL, it's with code.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399869/navigating-through-text-input-fields-using-arrow-keys-and-return

Answer (score 1):

Use this URL, it's with code.
[Navigating through text input fields using arrow keys and return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399869/navigating-through-text-input-fields-using-arrow-keys-and-return)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
           // get only input tags with class data-entry
           textboxes = $("input.data-entry");
           // now we check to see which browser is being used 
           if ($.browser.mozilla) { 
               $(textboxes).keypress (checkForAction);
              } 
          else { 
              $(textboxes).keydown (checkForAction); 
          } 
      });  

     function checkForAction (event) {
          if (event.keyCode == 13 || 40) {
             currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this); 
               if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) {
                   nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1]
                   nextBox.focus(); 
                   nextBox.select();
                   event.preventDefault();
                   return false;
               }
           } 
       }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur Response this help me lot

Comment: Happy to hear. please vote to my answer and mark it as the answer.

Comment: @st mnmn Thanks for this...Im trying to see how to move in a gridview with up and down arrow...this is a start.