# GridView to Insert a Row of records in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

How can I use a `GridView` like Excel sheet to enter records?  Just similar to Excel sheet, moving up / down in row using up / down arrow key.

I need to insert more than 25 records of single rows (say marks of student) which in enter by user against their registration number. I used `<ItemTemplate>` and `TextBox`es, but not found so flexible to enter marks of students.

Please help me if any other ways to do such task.

Answer (score 0):

To perform the moving up/down in row using up / down arrow key Use this URL: [Navigating through text input fields using arrow keys and return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399869/navigating-through-text-input-fields-using-arrow-keys-and-return), it's with code.

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){  
       // get only input tags with class data-entry 
       textboxes = $("input.data-entry"); 
       // now we check to see which browser is being used  
       if ($.browser.mozilla) {  
           $(textboxes).keypress (checkForAction); 
          }  
      else {  
          $(textboxes).keydown (checkForAction);  
      }  
  });   

 function checkForAction (event) { 
      if (event.keyCode == 13 || 40) { 
         currentBoxNumber = textboxes.index(this);  
           if (textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] != null) { 
               nextBox = textboxes[currentBoxNumber + 1] 
               nextBox.focus();  
               nextBox.select(); 
               event.preventDefault(); 
               return false; 
           } 
       }  
   } 
</script>
```